# Application insight causes errors in Typescript SPA

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, azure-application-insights

I'm working on a single page html application in VSCode using TypeScript.

The app was working fine, no errors, no warnings and I decided to add Azure Application Insight.

I installed it with: npm install --save @microsoft/applicationinsights-web

It created applicationinsights folders under node_modules and under @types\applicationinsights and also several "applicationinsights-*-js" folders under node_modules@microsoft.

Before adding any code, I added : import { ApplicationInsights } from "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web".

From that moment, tsc wasn't showing any error but the Problems tab in VSCode showed 121 errors, mostly my main objects are no longer recognised and the app is not starting.

I updated the tsconfig.json file to use: "target": "ES2022", "module": "ES6" and "moduleResolution": "node" but didn't helped.

Could you please me understand the issue here ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to TypeScript's failure to identify the types provided by the installed package.

- I have created a sample project `my-azure-appinsights` and installed TypeScript as a development dependency: `npm install --save-dev typescript`

This is my typescript configuration file: **tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    
    "target": "ES2022",                                  
    "module": "ES6",                                
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

**package.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "my-azure-appinsights",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Azure Application Insights example project",
  "main": "test.ts", 
  "type": "module", 
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/applicationinsights": "^0.20.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^3.0.5"
  }
}
```

**test.ts** file:

```
import { ApplicationInsights } from "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web";

// Initialize Application Insights
const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
  config: {
    instrumentationKey: "YOUR_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY",
  },
});

// Start tracking telemetry data
appInsights.loadAppInsights();

// Example event tracking
appInsights.trackEvent({ name: "SampleEvent" });
```

Here I compile typescript to JavaScript using **`npx tsc`**

[image]

After running the application using **`node test.js`**, I can get the custom event logs which is configured in the application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to update my solution with your hints and it didn't solved the issue, I will try on a smaller project.   I noticed that you mentioned "typescript": "^5.2.2" where  I have "^4.8.4", do you think it can play a role in my issue ?

Comment: @ClaudeVernier, yes `"typescript": "^5.2.2"`, which is a hypothetical version at the time of the response. If you are using TypeScript version `"^4.8.4"`, there might be some differences and improvements in later versions that could potentially address compatibility issues with certain packages.

Comment: I keep having issues... :(  I tried several things and it always come to different issues, either code doesn't compile because references are not found or it compiles but at run time, it doesn't find the applicationinsightsobjects. could you recommend a startup project I could use that uses typescript, applicationinsights and vscode ?